# SchematronParseError: invalid schematron schema (for ISOSTS schema)

Tags: python, lxml, schematron

I try to validate document using Schematron.

I use [schema for ISOSTS standard](http://www.iso.org/schema/isosts/resources/schematron/ISOSTS_validation.sch).

```
from lxml import etree
from lxml.isoschematron import Schematron   


def validate(self, filename: str):
    file = open(filename)

    schema_filename = join('/path/to/ISOSTS_validation.sch')
    schema_file = open(schema_filename)

    # fixme it works. But fails with ISOSTS scheme
    # schema_file = StringIO('''\
    #     <schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" >
    #       <pattern id="sum_equals_100_percent">
    #         <title>Sum equals 100%.</title>
    #         <rule context="Total">
    #           <assert test="sum(//Percent)=100">Sum is not 100%.</assert>
    #         </rule>
    #       </pattern>
    #     </schema>
    # ''')

    sct_doc = etree.parse(schema_file)
    schematron = Schematron(sct_doc)       ## <- FAIL !!!

    doc = etree.parse(file)
    result = schematron.validate(doc)

    file.close()
    schema_file.close()

    return result

validate('/path/to/feature_doc.xml')
```

Error message:

```
File "/var/www/.../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/lxml/isoschematron/__init__.py", line 279, in __init__
    schematron_schema_valid.error_log)
lxml.etree.SchematronParseError: invalid schematron schema: <string>:553:0:ERROR:RELAXNGV:RELAXNG_ERR_EXTRACONTENT: Element function has extra content: param
<string>:560:0:ERROR:RELAXNGV:RELAXNG_ERR_ELEMNAME: Expecting element schema, got variable
<string>:0:0:ERROR:RELAXNGV:RELAXNG_ERR_INTEREXTRA: Extra element function in interleave
<string>:42:0:ERROR:RELAXNGV:RELAXNG_ERR_CONTENTVALID: Element schema failed to validate content
```

How to repair it?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that it's terribly helpful, but I don't think the problem is in your code. I think the problem is that lxml doesn't support XSLT-2.

The schema you've used requires the 2010 XSLT-2 compliant ISO Schematron [1].

Opening the schema in Oxygen and removing the `querybinding=xslt2` attribute generates a raft of problems. This includes a validation error on line 553 (`<xsl:param name="num-cols" as="xs:integer"/>`): 'attribute is not allowed on this element'. This is the line that lxml is throwing the parse error on [2].

lxml does not implement XSTL-2, and states explicitly that it only supports "the pure-XSLT-1.0 [skeleton implementation](http://schematron.com/implementation.html)" of Schematron, (info from http://lxml.de/validation.html#id2).

You might be out of luck trying to get this to work with lxml at all. There isn't, to my knowledge, an XSLT-2 compatible Python XML parser (and if anyone knows of one, that would be fantastic).

It's a bit of a hack, but you can use subprocess to perform a validation using an external tool (crux + libsaxon, perhaps). That may be the only solution here.

[1] Line 35 of the linked schema:

`<schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"  queryBinding="xslt2"`

[2] `lxml.etree.SchematronParseError: invalid schematron schema: <string>:553:0:ERROR:RELAXNGV:RELAXNG_ERR_EXTRACONTENT: Element function has extra content: param`

Answer (score 0):

Solved using xsd schema [from archive](http://www.iso.org/schema/isosts/isosts-v1.1.zip) and `lxml.etree.XMLSchema`:

```
def validate(self, filename: str):
    file = open(filename)

    schema_filename = '/path/to/ISOSTS.xsd'
    schema_file = open(schema_filename)

    sct_doc = etree.parse(schema_file)
    xmlschema = etree.XMLSchema(sct_doc)

    doc = etree.parse(file)
    result = xmlschema.validate(doc)

    file.close()
    schema_file.close()

    return result
```